# I'm not able to switch to tabs in the bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm very new to html world and I'm trying to build some sample summary report and I need to implement tab to show case Executive summary and Test summary details as below:

[image]

I just implemented bootstrap tab and when I tried to click the tabs nothing is displayed.

HTML BODY:

```
<body>

    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col>
            <col>
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">EXECUTION SUMMARY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Platform</td>
            <td>Android</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Device Details</td>
            <td>Android Mobile v12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Application Details</td>
            <td>BEAM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Build Details</td>
            <td>17.6.0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total CUJ's</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Passed CUJ's</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Failed CUJ's</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

   <!-- Tabs navs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="ex1" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link active"
        id="ex1-tab-1"
        data-mdb-toggle="tab"
        href="#ex1-tabs-1"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="ex1-tabs-1"
        aria-selected="true"
        >Executive Summary</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="ex1-tab-2"
        data-mdb-toggle="tab"
        href="#ex1-tabs-2"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="ex1-tabs-2"
        aria-selected="false"
        >Test Summary</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="ex1-tab-3"
        data-mdb-toggle="tab"
        href="#ex1-tabs-3"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="ex1-tabs-3"
        aria-selected="false"
        >Tab 3</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tabs navs -->

  <div class="tab-content" id="ex1-content">
    <div
    class="tab-pane fade show active"
    id="ex1-tabs-1"
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-1">
        <h1 style="margin-left:50px">CUJ's :</h1>
        <div class="first">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <br/>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">D+ Base Line Data (16.6.1)</h3>
                    <div class="progress red">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%;  background-color:#FFE4C4;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">App Launch: </h3>
                    <div class="progress green">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 90%;  background-color:#FF6347;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="second">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <br/>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">D+ Base Line Data (16.6.1)</h3>
                    <div class="progress red">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%;  background-color:#FFE4C4;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">Success Auth: </h3>
                    <div class="progress green">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 90%;  background-color:#FF6347;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <br/>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">D+ Base Line Data (16.6.1)</h3>
                    <div class="progress red">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%;  background-color:#FFE4C4;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">Search: </h3>
                    <div class="progress green">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 90%;  background-color:#FF6347;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <br/>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">D+ Base Line Data (16.6.1)</h3>
                    <div class="progress red">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 80%;  background-color:#FFE4C4;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">VST: </h3>
                    <div class="progress green">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%;  background-color:#00FF00;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="five">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <br/>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">D+ Base Line Data (16.6.1)</h3>
                    <div class="progress red">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%;  background-color:#FFE4C4;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">Add Profile: </h3>
                    <div class="progress green">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 80%;  background-color:#FF6347;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="six">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <br/>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">D+ Base Line Data (16.6.1)</h3>
                    <div class="progress red">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 90%;  background-color:#FFE4C4;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="progress-title">Remove Profile: </h3>
                    <div class="progress green">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%;  background-color:#00FF00;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex1-tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-2">
            Tab 2 content
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

HTML link and Script:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.2.0/mdb.min.js"/>
    </head>
```

Tab is not working in the above snippet. Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Please provide complete detail like which bootstrap version are you using bcoz you have included the cdn for v3.3 and you have using tabbing code for v4(i guess).Second thing what is this (data-mdb-toggle="tab" ) as there is no any mention for such in bootstrap. And your placement for tabbing code is wrong.